# How I can launch my browser and Nautilus using defaults Ubuntu 12.04 shortcut?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, shortcut-keys, launcher, desktop-environments

In keyboard shortcut settings I see a launcher section that have 'WWW' and 'Explorer' labels inside the key combination column of the shortcut definition. What keys I must press to launch my browser and my file explorer in Ubuntu 12.04 if I want use the default system shortcuts.?

Comment: I believe those are the dash shortcuts. Hit the super key (start key on most keyboards), type in www and the browser app will be your first choice. Same with typing Mail. I think if you want an actual keyboard shortcut, you will have to set one yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If you put your comment as a reply, I can select it as the answer to my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a shortcut for opening Nautilus or your browser, open system settings, go to "Keyboard" and switch to the "Shortcuts" tab.

Select "Custom Shortcuts" and click the "Plus" (+) button, give it a name and put 'nautilus' in the command field. Then click "Apply".

[image]

In this case you will see a new shortcut called "Open Nautilus" that is disabled.  Click on "Disabled" and enter the shortcut you want.

This will work for your browser as well, you just have to know its command.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is know how use the *default* shortcut for Nautilus and Browser.

Comment: @gsc-frank There isn't a _default_ shortcut, what you are seeing is _dash_ shortcuts, like a comment said.